# What is a "graceful exit" in Java?

Tags: java

My Beginner Java college instructor constantly refers to a user terminating a program as "exiting the program gracefully", both on his grading remarks and in class. For example, after a user finishes adding scores to an array, typing -1 would signify they are ready for the program to average the scores and output the answers.

I thought in programming a graceful exit is where you allow the program a way to terminate infinite loop errors and such. Is exiting gracefully a specific vocabulary for a specific event, or does it mean different things to different people?

Comment: mjb2kmn is correct, in that `System.exit()` is the method to call when you are ready for the program to stop.  What you are considering is "does the system exit gracefully under aberrant and unexpected circumstances". In that case the correct implementation of exception handling in your code will eventually lead to a call to `System.exit()` in a safe and controlled manner.

Answer (score 5):

A "graceful exit" would be anything other than a "crash", or a force kill signal.

Calling `System.exit()` in a Java application would be a graceful exit.

If the program crashes or is force killed, exit or shutdown hooks would not be fired. A graceful exit would allow the program to finalize writing files, or closing connections, etc.